# HP Envy 15 keeps restarting instead of installing Ubuntu 12.10 from usb stick

Tags: live-usb, hp, restart

I have set the bios to boot using the usb stick and I can get to a menu that asks if I would like to try Ubuntu or install it. When I choose install, it asks me if I want to install Ubuntu inside of windows 7, which I choose. But then, the whole thing goes to a black screen and a bunch of console jargon scrolls on the screen for a while and before I know it, I'm back to the menu asking if I want to try or install Ubuntu again. If I select install, the same thing happens again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem on an HP machine. The problem was that the machine only allows four partitions, and HP had installed an *HP tools* partition.

I solved the problem by deleting the *HP tools* partition and shrinking the Windows 7 partition with Windows Disk Manager. After that, the Ubuntu installer says "install *alongside* Windows", and everything worked as expected.